# How can I put a data inside the <template> in a component with Vue

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to do a pagination but I can not put the dynamic total I am doing like this:

```
<v-pagination v-model="currentPage" 
                        :page-count="total"
                        :classes="bootstrapPaginationClasses"
                        :labels="paginationAnchorTexts"
                        ></v-pagination>
```

How you can see the total os in the :page-count, it is a dynamic total because I am getting data from database, my vue code is this one:

```
<script>
import vPagination from 'vue-plain-pagination';

export default {
    created() {
        this.getPosts();
    },
    methods: {
        getPosts() {
            fetch('/api/bank')
            .then(response => response.json() )
            .then(json => { 
                this.posts = json.data.data;
                this.total = json.data.last_page;
                this.current_page = json.data.current_page;
            });
        }
    },
    components: { vPagination },
    data: function() {
        return {
            postsSelected: "",
            posts: [],
            currentPage: 1,
            total: this.total,
            bootstrapPaginationClasses: {
                ul: 'pagination',
                li: 'page-item',
                liActive: 'active',
                liDisable: 'disabled',
                button: 'page-link'  
            },
            paginationAnchorTexts: {
                first: 'Primera',
                prev: '&laquo;',
                next: '&raquo;',
                last: 'Última'
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

How you can see I am using fetch to get the data from database and then I am split it in different information like total and the I am using this information inside the data: function() {}.

How you can tell total it's like this: total: this.total because I want to get the total number but when I do that I am getting this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "pageCount". Expected Number with value NaN, got Undefined
```

and I think that it is because:

1. total: this.total in the data function() {} is bad or:
2. how can I put the dynamic variable total inside the

How could I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't create data properties with the same name as props

Comment: @Phil I got same problem and I update the code, error: [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "pageCount". Expected Number with value NaN, got Undefined, what could it be?

Comment: In the data property just add `total: 0,` . Hope this will solve your issue. Also check if you're getting data from api and print the value of `json.data.last_page` just to be sure.

Comment: @beingyogi but if I add total: 0 how can I know the total data from database? because I am getting this data from fetch this.total

Comment: You can have a look at vue reactivity in detail [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the data retrieved from the API, you can console log the data returned like this:

```
getPosts() {
            fetch('/api/bank')
            .then(response => response.json() )
            .then(json => { 
                console.log(json.data)
                this.posts = json.data.data;
                this.total = json.data.last_page;
                this.current_page = json.data.current_page;
            });
        }
```

Also, you should not have data attribute and props attribute with the same name! So change the `total` data attribute to another name and initialize it with a value of 0 instead.

In fact, you don't need to care about passing the Prop total at all as your method getPosts is not dependent on the Prop! So you may just have `total: 0` in data and that should fix your issues