# Creating an edit form with Vue + Axios - Adding a dynamic value from database to the form input

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to do an edit form with Vue + Axios but I have a conflict... My Vue code:

```
<script>
  import {
    required,
    minLength
  } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

export default {
  created() {
    this.getPost();
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      form: {
        name: ""
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getPost() {
      axios.get('/api/bank/' + this.$route.params.id + '/edit')
        .then(response => {
          this.post = response.data.data;
        });
    },
    onSubmit() {
      if (this.formValid) {
        axios.put('/api/bank/update/' + this.$route.params.id, {
            name: this.$v.form.name.$model
          })
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log('enviado' + this.form.name);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });

        this.$refs.editBank.reset(); // This will clear that form

        this.$awn.success("El registro ha sido actualizado", {
          labels: {
            success: "Éxito"
          }
        });

        this.$router.push('/bank');
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    formValid() {
      return !this.$v.$invalid;
    }
  },
  validations: {
    form: {
      name: {
        required,
        minLength: minLength(2)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

How you can see I am getting the data from database in the function getPost() but I want to put that value in the form, I mean when I go to this page in the input automaticly displays the value so I have my input like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" 
                            v-model="$v.form.name.$model"
                            :class="{
                                'is-valid':!$v.form.name.$error && $v.form.name.$dirty,
                                'is-invalid':$v.form.name.$error && $v.form.name.$dirty
                            }"
                            placeholder="Ingresa el nombre del banco"
                            :value="post.bank"
                            >
```

how you can see I use :value="post.bank" to add the value but when I do that it displays an error:

Errors compiling template:

:value="post.bank" conflicts with v-model on the same element because the latt                                                                             er already expands to a value binding internally
22 |                                  'is-invalid':$v.form.name.$error && $v.f                                                                             orm.name.$dirty
23 |                              }"
24 |                              placeholder="Ingresa el nombre del banco"
|
25 |                              :value="post.bank"
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
26 |

So I wonder what it's the problem? It's says that :value is two times but it is not two times..

How can I fix it?

Because if I remove the :value so how can I add a dynamic value?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `:value` as `v-model` already takes care of two-way binding between the data attribute and view.

Change your `v-model` to `v-model="form.name"`

Change your getPost method to the following:

```
getPost() {
      axios.get('/api/bank/' + this.$route.params.id + '/edit')
        .then(response => {
          this.post = response.data.data;
          this.$set(this.form, 'name', response.data.data.name)
        });
    },
```

Comment: But if I remove the :value how can I set the value in the input? @Ayudh

Comment: The v-model will take care of setting the value in the input automatically.

Comment: Ok I remove :value but it displays none I mean an empty input with no value, so I wonder how can I add that dynamic value here  data: function() {
            return {
                form: {
                    name: ""
                }
            }
        },

Comment: Just do `v-model="form.name"`

Comment: It's like that v-model="$v.form.name.$model"

Comment: Can you try `v-model="form.name"`

Comment: Where are you calling the getPost method? The input shows nothing but are you calling the getPost in `created()` ?

Comment: getPost in the created() and I put v-model="form.name" and it returns no error but an empty input, because I initializate v-model data: function() { return { form: { name: "" } } }

Comment: So then... where are you assigning a name ?

Comment: That is the thing because if I do this data: function() {
            return {
                form: {
                    name: this.post.bank
                }
            }
        } it displays this error then [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'bank' of undefined"

Comment: How can I fix it? :(

Comment: Could you upvote my answer in `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64344563/how-can-i-put-a-data-inside-the-template-in-a-component-with-vue/64345729#64345729` as well. Thanks!